# In perspective, circle becomes an ellipse. but why isn't the center of circle, center of ellipse?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, projective-geometry, projection, projection-matrices

In perspective view (a projection), when you look at the circle from different angles, it becomes an ellipse.  (also in the world).  Most things make sense with perspective, but I don't see why the center of the circle doesn't match the center of the ellipse (just the fact of geometric intersection?).  I like to draw, so I'm curious.

Comment: It does.${}{}{}$

Comment: but no same place, perspective view

Comment: When things are further away, they appear closer together. The centre lies equidistant between the point on the circle closest to you and the point furthest away. Because the centre and the further point are the same distance, but further away from you, than the centre and the closer point, naturally, the centre will appear closer to the further point.

Comment: @TheoBendit: The OP specifically mentioned a _projection_. In this case, the two centres coincide.

Comment: @TonyK It depends on the type of projection, but regardless, I suspect that the argument in my comment is the sort of thing that the OP will be interested in.

Comment: i know perspective rule. ok but ellipse center Isn't it related to anything?

Comment: I read somewhere that the image of the ellipse cannot be restored to the circle.

Comment: Similar question: why a set of equidistant parallel lines do not appear equidistant in perspective?

Comment: As I understand it, the circle looks like an ellipse in perspective.very symmetrical ellipse, the midpoints cannot intersect for perspective reasons.

Comment: Unless you clarify what perspective and/or projection you mean, this is unanswerable. As it is, for a natural orthogonal projection, the answer is that you're wrong, they do intersect, so you must have more conditions not included here.

Answer (score 2):

This is explained without words in the following schematic where the bottom black line segment is the circle lying horizontally, and projection plane is shown in green.  Point O is where all the rays converge.  It can be seen that the projection of the center of the circle is not halfway between the two extremities of the projection of the circle.

[image]

Comment: Must be for the same reason in the circle placed inside the square.